# How to display matrix file in rows and columns

Tags: c++

pardon my code formatting as I have just started out in C++.
Anyway, I am trying to read and display the contents (in the form of matrix) from a text file.

While I am able to read in the file, instead of displaying the outputs as how it should be as in its text file, I am getting the contents all in a single line. I can't brute force the code as I have several file where its matrix is different.

Eg. matrix01

```
9 7 6
8 -1 0
```

Or matrix02

```
2 10
3 5
-7 25
```

The following code is the my file input, and so what can I do to make it out in rows and columns instead of a single row/line?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    ifstream fin;  //file input stream
    ofstream fout; //file output stream

    fin.open("/Desktop/matrix_a.txt");
    fout.open("/Desktop/matrix_a.out");
    string msg;


    while (fin>>msg){//read until eof
      cout << msg << " ";
    }


    fin.close();
    fout.close();

}
```

Comment: Edited my code, that is an extras/typo I have inputted

Answer (score 2):

You state:

> I am getting the contents all in a single line.

Your code does the following:

```
 while (fin>>msg){//read until eof
   cout << "" << msg << " ";
 }
```

This is because you do not write a `std::endl` to `std::cout`, here, and you do not end up printing a newline at any time. `operator<<` does not automatically add a newline at the end of the statement. It is your responsibility to do, if so desired.

Comment: Hi.. I did tried adding in `endl`, using the matrix01 as example, instead of getting 2 lines/rows, I will end up getting 6 lines/rows instead

Comment: operator>> reads a single whitespace delimited word. If you want to read one line at a time, use std::getline() instead of operator>>

Comment: @dissidia you have to store the information of how many rows (and clomuns) you read from file, so you can add a newline after each row you'll print (among other useful things you can do with that information).